# Where can I find the freeware ST-Links PgMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcgis-9.3, download, st-links

I am trying to connect to a PostGIS database from ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1
Some web-searching suggested that zigGIS would be useful. Unfortunately zigGIS has reached the end of life, and the author of zigGIS recommended the use of freeware PgMap [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ziggis/FK6KNRVk3p4/5IpuC9coAOMJ)

Further research suggested that ST-Links has renamed PgMap to SpatialKit and is now charging for it.

Is the freeware version of PgMap still available to download? If so where?

Answer (score 1):

I just found ST-Links SpatialKit Version 3.0.3 for ArcMap 9.3 (last update April 12, 2012) available for download [**here**](http://www.st-links.com/Pages/Download.aspx).

Comment: I did try that; It comes with a limit of 100 features. If your table has more than that, then only the first 100 features are shown.

Comment: request a free license and you can overcome the 100 records limit.

Answer (score 1):

you can request free license. It issues free license to all users by request.

Comment: Ok, I have written an email to them. Let's see if they can help.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Were you able to get this resolved?  If so, it would be good to get an Accept tick on one or other of the answers.

Comment: @PolyGeo: No, i did not get a response from them.